# Undefined control sequence by reference LYX, MikTex

Tags: lyx, miktex, koma-script, fancyhdr

For each reference I put in to the document, I get the following error message. What should I do?

```
Undefined control sequence

Document Class: scrreprt 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (report)

    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \lhead{}
    \chead{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}

 ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> ...hr mit den H�nden ber�hren.``\citet 
                                                      {DMS Aplizieren}
    l.1333 ...�nden ber�hren.``\citet{DMS Aplizieren}}

    The control sequence at the end of the top line
    of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
    misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
    spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
    and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: use `\"a` instead of `ä`, so `mit den H\"anden`. Simliar for the other umlauts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick esponse but it does not work! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\emph {\"a}nden ber\"uhren.``\citet 
                                                  {DMS Aplizieren}
l.1333 ...den ber\"uhren.``\citet{DMS Aplizieren}}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: even if i delete all umlaute i get the same error

Answer (score 3):

The `\citet` command is not available by default in LaTeX, you need to load a bibliography package that defines it. In LyX, go to Document --> Settings --> Bibliography and set *Natbib* as Citation style. This loads the `natbib` package, where `\citet` and `\citep` are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Now these errors are away but 

Now i get an an other error
Package Natbib error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citation

Comment: @ChristianAustria Ok. In Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, have you selected *Numerical* or *Author-year* as Natbib-style? Which *Bibliography style* have you chosen for your bibliography? (Try `plainnat`.) If you're unable to fix it, I would recommend asking a new question about this issue, including details about how your document and bibliography is set up. It is generally best to have just one problem per question.

Comment: I choose natbib   author-year

do i have to load a package for plainnat because i cannot see it

Ok I'm going to make a new question. thanks for Helping

Comment: @ChristianAustria `plainnat` is from `natbib`, but you shouldn't need to do anything special I think, it should be in the *Style* dropdown menu in the window that appears when you do Insert --> List/TOC --> BibTeX bibliography (or if you click on an existing `BibTeX Generated Bibliography`).